# How to refer ephemeral model in pre/post hook of an incremental model

Tags: dbt

I have an incremental model which is  upserting the data. I want to delete the data from this model on the basis of time period column which is coming from one of the ephemeral model.
I have referenced ephemeral model in pre hook using 'ref' function but it is not replicating the CTE.

It is generating SQL as below
Delete from abc.xyz where time_period in (select distinct time_period from __dbt__CTE__ephemeral_model)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the process that generates the CTE you're expecting is baked into the model materialisations and therefore doesn't get compiled properly when you put it in a pre-hook or post-hook (or a macro).

It is likely that your best option would be to build the ephemeral model as a view instead, which works well from the tests I've run.

Alternatively, you could write a macro that is passed to the pre-hook and include the full logic of the ephemeral model in the macro.

Comment: Thank you for reply @dylanbaker. Actually I don't want to create a db object hence I want to use ephemeral model. View will be an option definitely but is there any alternative to call ephemeral models in pre/post hook

Comment: I would need one of the maintainers to weigh in, but at first glance, it doesn't appear so. I think the alternative I would suggest (and can add to the response) is to reference a macro in the pre-hook, and include the ephemeral model logic in the macro itself.

Comment: Thank you @dylanbaker. I am going ahead with your suggestion. Instead of table I will create a view and use it in pre/post hook.